# Searching for the name of a cartoon which was broadcast on Cartoon Network (India) between 1999 and 2003

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

I am searching for the name of a cartoon which was broadcast on Cartoon Network (India) between 1998 and 2002. This cartoon aired around 4:30. The cartoon seemed to be Japan-made.

The cartoon depicted battles which happen in space. The main characters were two boys and a girl. There was a spaceship which these people live on, and there was a princess which they had to save from villains.

A super hero appeared whenever conflict arose, and one of the main characters took control of this hero. He got support from others, too - when he joins with his friends they can change as dragon and tiger.

Comment: 1998-2002, or 1999-2003? The title and question disagree, and did so even in the first revision.

Answer (score 3):

Is this [Tobikage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ninja_Senshi_Tobikage)? The main characters of Tobikage are three teenagers: Joe Maya, and his friends Rena Ai (Jenny Ai in some translated versions) and Mike Coil:

[image]

They are protecting Romina, princess of the planet Ladorio:

[image]

They are later joined by a young man from Mars, Damian:

[image]

Joe pilots a giant robot ninja named Tobikage - that would be the "hero" you remember. And there are actually three robot animals, not two - Mike pilots the dragon, Damian pilots the lion (the one you remember as a tiger), and Rena pilots a hawk robot. The three robots can each merge with Tobikage to form a powered-up robot:

[image]